# dismissViewControllerAnimated does not work within a block

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I try to close a `UIViewController` after an `UIAlertController` has been shown.

This is my code:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title 
                                                                         message:msg
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Accept" 
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault 
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
             {
                 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
             }];

[alertController addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

However, `self` never gets dismissed. Anyone knows how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

if I set `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` outside of the block, it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case someone is having the same issue. I pushed the `UIViewController`, I didn't present it with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. That's why **`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`** should be used instead.

The strange thing is that `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` worked outside of the block and didn't inside, I have no explanation for this...

Answer (score 13):

Just use `[super.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Yes... that's what I wrote 4 month earlier :D

Answer (score 5):

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` will close any view controllers that the *currently displaying view* (i.e., "self") is displaying. What you want to do is run this same method on the *presenting* view controller for "self". I.e.

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: but self (the current UIViewController) is the view I want to dismiss. I tried adding .parentViewController, it makes no difference.

Comment: Yep, exactly. You want to dismiss "self". "self.presentingViewController" might do it. Updating the answer.

Comment: In the debugger, are both "self.presentingViewController" and "self.parentViewController" nil?

Comment: no, `self.parentViewController` is of type `XXXRootNavigationController`

Comment: How about `self.presentingViewController`?

Comment: `self.presentingViewController` is nil

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked on which thread the block is being called on?  If it's not thread 1, then it won't dismiss your view properly, as UI manipulation can only be done on thread one.  Try creating a method for dismissing and then calling it on the main thread:

```
    ...handler {
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismissModalView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}];

-(void)dismissModalView {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: yep, tried it, it did not work. BTW, the shortest selector is `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`