# How to dismiss view in swift? dismissViewControllerAnimated is not doing anything?

Tags: swift

I have an issue where dismissViewController method is not actually doing anything. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class CameraController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    ....

    @IBAction func dismissPhotoPicker(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("in the function")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

No errors are thrown when running, click on the button does trigger the method (I put a print statement in the function)

There are 2 buttons "Back", which calls that method, and another one called "Open Image Picker", which opens the Image Picker.

My storyboard starts with a TabBarViewController, I set up a segue such that when clicking on the "Camera" button, it switches to the "CameraViewController", which is associated with the custom class CameraController (which I've specified in my Storyboard.xib file)

Comment: Are you trying to dismiss the UIImagePickerController? If so, can you show the code where you present it? ...and maybe the  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate functions...

Comment: "Click on the button does trigger the method". Have you connected the @IBAction from nib?

Comment: @avismara Yes, when clicking on the "Back" button, I see "in the function" printed out in the console.

Comment: @Mark Watson, no I am trying to dismiss the current view controller. The user has to click on another button in the same view controller to open the image picker.

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070015/dismissviewcontrolleranimated-does-not-work-within-a-block

Comment: You are probably using UINavigationController. If so you have to use "self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)" instead of "dismissViewControllerAnimated" method

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
yourView:UIView {
  // do something
}

yourMainController:UIViewController {
  let view = yourView()

  func showView() {
    self.view.addSubview(view)
  }

  func hideView() {
    view.removeFromSuperView()
  }
}
```

Comment: No errors triggered, but does not actually dismiss the view... I see print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if self.isBeingPresented() {
        // being presented
        print("being present, going to dismiss..")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } else if self.isMovingToParentViewController() {
          // being pushed
          print("being pushed, going to pop..")
          if let navController = self.navigationController {
                 navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
          }
    } else {
        // simply showing again because another VC was dismissed
    }
```