# Cordova view unresponsive after plugin returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, auth0

I'm trying to make auth0 lock for iOS work with cordova. It seems to work except I'm doing something wrong when I'm dismissing the view after the plugin is done. It gets dismissed but I can no longer interact with the cordova view. It becomes unresponsive.

Here is the plugin code:

```
@implementation lockPlugin

-(void)init:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {

    A0Lock *lock = [A0Lock sharedLock];

    A0LockViewController *controller = [lock newLockViewController];
    controller.onAuthenticationBlock = ^(A0UserProfile *profile, A0Token *token) {

        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
                                                messageAsDictionary:@{
                                                                      @"idToken":token.idToken,
                                                                      @"refreshToken":token.refreshToken,
                                                                      @"tokenType":token.tokenType,
                                                                      @"accessToken":token.accessToken,
                                                                      @"email":profile.email
                                                                      }];

        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];

        [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    };
    [lock presentLockController:controller fromController:self.viewController];

}
@end
```

Comment: You've used Auth0 for iOS instead of Auth0 for Cordova. I haven't been able to find examples of Cordova segueing to native iOS and there may be some gotchas there. Can you elaborate on why you chose this option?

Comment: @RoyFalk I wanted to have native look and feel for the login. The weird thing is that sometimes it works just fine.

Comment: if you open the project on Xcode, do you see some message on the console?

Comment: @jcesarmobile It dismisses the lock view but then I cannot interact with the cordova. No errors and safari dev tools still works so I can still execute js in console.

Comment: native errors don't appear on safari console, can you open the Xcode project and try running from there? It's on platforms/ios, just double click the .xcodeproj

Comment: @jcesarmobile There are no errors/warnings in xcode regarding the plugin or anything else when the plugin is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit your code looks good and I can't find anything wrong with it or on Google. I did find some references to race condition, which brings me to the latest and last idea...

dismissViewControllerAnimated is called from CDVPluginResult with a reference to CDVPluginResult.viewController and not the original viewController. The action itself is animated, which means takes a while and by that time, the reference is to nil. Alternatively, it seems you shouldn't call dismiss from a block, as it isn't the UI thread. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070015/dismissviewcontrolleranimated-does-not-work-within-a-block) seems to support my second theory. Try doing

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

=============================================================================

The fact that it works is weird. You're placing your lock variable in a local context within the init method and the [Auth0 for iOS docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-ios) say you should "keep it in your AppDelegate as a strong property...keep it alive as long as you need it." Since it's a local variable in init, it should be deallocated as soon as the method terminates.

Perhaps the session check is made every x seconds and the app sometimes has enough grace period to work and load the new screen.

Comment: I'm using the plugin to get the token and it sends the results to cordova. Auth is not an issue as I get the token and it all works. The trouble I have is dismissing the view correctly.

Comment: This worked. I had to add a UINavigationController and present lockController with that. Thanks!

Comment: It works but not all the time. I accepted the answer but this thing is driving me nuts as there is no way to reproduce it reliably.

Comment: Can you add some NSLog? Within the UI thread before/after dismiss 2. In prepareForDealloc or dealloc. This could hint at the problem.

Comment: The order is correct. I was able to filter the issue down to signupviewcontroller of auth0. Login view works fine but if I go through the signup, it does not work.